# Which cases to return 400 HTTP Code in Rest Api

Tags: rest, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I have some doubts when to return a 400 Http Code in any rest api. I explain the next three  cases:

1. When some of parameters values dont match with the requirements, for example, the length of a string, or a range for a number I would return a 400
2. When a user wants to execute some "action" in our system but before it, we apply some businness logic to validate this request and if its valid we execute that action, if the validation is KO, should we return 400?. I would
3. The final one and more confusing to me, what about if we expose some rest method call that its purpose is just to validate something with businnes logic rules, like for example we expose a method in order the client can call us to validate the shopping of some items, should we return 400 in this case if any of the bussiness validation rules did not pass? I think I would not because the final goal of this request is to validate something and this has been executed succesfully although in the validation process some of the bussiness validation rules did not passed.

Do you agree? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For 1) and 2) a 400 http status code should be returned.

For 3) it is depending on the business validation rule. If it is due to user rights, 403 would be a proper http status code. If something is due to resources that are not present (any more) 404 would be the status code to choose. Also 409 is a status code that could be useful in many business rule scenarios.
In any case where no other 4xx status code seems indented, use 400.

Look here for a complete list of http status codes and the description for them:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5

Comment: What I meant with point 3, is that maybe I should return a 200 and in the response the business validation rule message that failed

Comment: No that would definitely be wrong. 200 means success, if anything, whatever it might be, fails you can not send a status 200.

Comment: But if the method itself like I mentioned is about just to apply validation rules and one rule is he cannot buy 5 items , should I return some 400 for example? The request is good, the processing is ok

Comment: No, 400 means EVERYTHING is ok. And that means everything is good. When the user should be notified about something that wasn't as expected, 400 is not the one you would choose. If however the user would buy 5 items but only 4 are being bought and the user would not want to know about this (which would seem very strange to me) then 400 would be the way to go. But as I mentioned, that would not make a lot of sense since you always want to tell the user about things that were done differently then expected.

Comment: I dont see why I cannot send a 200 in case 3, since the goal of the method is just to validate itself and it executed ok, there were no malformed parameters, etc. Its like sending an http request to know if I can hire something, so the answer would be false or true and if its false I send a 400 http status code to the client? To me is confusing that as a client, I send this request and I get 400 and I dont know if the request was processed or not., in this case, if the request was validated or not

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle is to return a 400 HTTP status code whenever the client's request is not as expected (missing mandatory parameters, malformed content, etc.)

So, for case 1) you should return 400.

For case 2) and 3), it depends on the specific validation rule. For example, if your validation rule is about the structure or the values of the request's content or something else that the client can fix, then you can return 400.

If the validation rule involves some way the authorization context, you should use 401, 403, or even 404.
Take a look at this article for more details: https://auth0.com/blog/forbidden-unauthorized-http-status-codes/

Comment: What I meant with point 3, is that maybe I should return a 200 and in the response the business validation rule message that failed

Comment: If you want to comply with REST guidelines, you should return 200 when everything is ok.
If there is something that the client can do to fix its request, you should return a 4xx status code